# How to replace content using regex

Tags: php, mysql, regex, wordpress

I have a problem with my db. The site I'm working on was using an old cms that had a very strange db structure and links weren't normal but some custom short code version. And now when the site was migrated to wordpress those links were replaced by some script. But it skipped about 2k of articles in the db (we have about 27k articles). What I was able to find is that these are the possible combination for my problem.

```
<a href="{{article::4111}}">Article title</a>
<a href="{{article::4111}}">{{article:4111}}</a>
or just {{article::4111}}
```

This is an example of the article:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque
faucibus vehicula mauris. Quisque sed ex ac lacus tempus blandit. 
Fusce in leo sit <a alt="Some text" title="other text" href="{{article::4111}}">{{article::4111}}</a> nisi porttitor volutpat ac vel tellus. Donec in 
pellentesque nunc. Maecenas congue libero dui, id fermentum ligula 
consequat ac. Suspendisse tempus magna lorem, nec facilisis dolor 
sodales at. Donec laoreet at justo non {{article::4511}}. Lorem ipsum dolor 
sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam porttitor, orci nec 
molestie interdum, libero est molestie sapien, efficitur facilisis mi 
diam non enim. Etiam viverra dolor ut augue vestibulum, placerat 
condimentum magna tincidunt. Integer rhoncus nulla at elit sodales 
pharetra. Maecenas congue erat ut tellus imperdiet molestie. Sed sed 
metus tincidunt, finibus ante quis, consequat orci. Nam non massa nec 
ipsum congue pretium. Curabitur sollicitudin, dui vitae venenatis 
hendrerit, tortor massa mattis nisl, vel rutrum enim nibh in tortor.
Related news:
{{article::75145}}
```

What I was thinking is to use php and regex to find this and replace it with a normal link, but my problem is I don't know regex that well and I need some sort of check to see which of the possible scenarios is. So if anyone has encountered a problem like this I would really appreciate some help. But main problem is that this can be found in any part of the article and random amount of times (it can be only one, or it could be like ten or twenty) and the part after :: is the ID of the article and is random , so to use classic explode function won't work. What I have done so far is exported my wp_posts table and imported into a custom db and have a clean php project connected only to that table and I will be using plain PHP and not wp functions. So what I need to do if it only located inside of `href=""` tag only I need to replace it with a full link but if it is located between `<a> </a>` and a `href=""` tag I need to replace the href tag with a link and the second part with the title. Sorry for such a long description but I thought it would help best describe my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match these it's quite simple: `/{{article::\d+}}/` This matches *article::* followed by one or more numbers. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oF5gZ4/2).

To replace all of them in a given string, use something, like this:

```
<?php
$str = '<a href="{{article::4111}}">Article title</a>
<a href="{{article::4111}}">{{article::4111}}</a>
or just {{article::4111}}
';

$str = preg_replace_callback(
   '/{{article::(\d+)}}/',
   function($match){
      // some callback function, where $match[1] contains the number
      // here we just add a path with the number as argument for a file article.php
      return 'http://domain.com/article.php?id='.$match[1];
   },
   $str
);

echo $str;
?>
```

In the function you can also make some DB calls or anything else to get the new URL.

Comment: hi @Reeno  , this is good but this will place the link inside of an a href tag but, also but the link a text displayed to the user. Is there an option to check if it is located between <a> </a> and place some text or just add url prefix to  matched number ? Thanks

Comment: Do you still need a solution to match the link text? In your example, the link text was provided without a placeholder. It's very hard to match complicated HTML with regex (and yes, that would be complicated). Mayo's solution works on some HTML, but not everytime. If the HTML structure has to be examined, you'd need some XML parsing.

Comment: no I don't. I was able to use your regex and than just modified it a bit and tested it and it worked. That is why I marked you as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/((\<a href=\")\{\{.*?\}\}(\">)\{\{.*?\}\}(<\/a\>)|\{\{.*?\}\})/gm
```

https://regex101.com/r/sN9rT2/1